# Changing php form to submit a styled email (HTML email)

Tags: php, html, css, email

When I submit my form, I receive the email in plain text and not quite in the format I'd like it to be. I'd like it to at least have color to the body and arrange the email so that its neater.

on the contact.php form ... this is what I currently have:

```
     $msg  = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to Accommodation. 
They passed verification and their message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "$comments" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "You can contact $name via email, $email or via phone $phone." . 
PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
     $msg .= "We want to stay from the $dayin to the $dayout" . PHP_EOL . 
PHP_EOL;
```

Why is this form using $msg? I've seen in other forms, they use $message. 
Can I add CSS styling to the above form?
I also see:

```
        $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;
```

Would I need to change "plain" to "HTML"?
Any suggestions or examples would be great!

---

EDIT:

Ok so now my header are:

```
    $headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"  . "\r\n" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n" . 
 PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;
```

Do I need PHP_EOL in each header?

My $msg looks like:

```
$msg  = '<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
color: #4D241E;
}
body {
background-image: url();
background-color: #F1EAE4;
 }
.style1 {font-size: 14px}
-->
</style>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="420" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
<td><table width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#E7D3AF" 
class="style">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" valign="top"><div align="center"><strong><span 
class="style1">Submission / Enquiry from your website</span><br>

&nbsp;........................................................................
</strong><br>
&nbsp;</div></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="32%" valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Date Submitted</strong>
 </div></td>
    <td width="68%" valign="top">'. date("F j, Y, g:i a") .'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Name</strong></div></td>
    <td valign="top">'.$_POST['name'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Email</strong></div></td>
    <td valign="top">'.$_POST['email'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Phone</strong></div></td>
    <td valign="top">'.$_POST['phone'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Day in</strong></div></td>
    <td valign="top">'.$_POST['dayin'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Day out</strong></div></td>
    <td valign="top">'.$_POST['dayout'].'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div align="left"><strong>Comments</strong></div></td>
    <td valign="top">'.$_POST['comments'].'</td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
 </table>
';
```

EDIT:
MY NEW HTML EMAIL DESIGN:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<!--DWLayoutTable-->
<tr>
<td width="12" height="14"></td>
<td width="140"></td>
<td width="432"></td>
<td width="16"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="71"></td>
<td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F5F5F5"><span style="font-
family:Arial; font-size:18px; color:#333333;"><strong>Submission from</strong>
</span><br />
<span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:16px; color:#f9930f;">
<em>Your website</em></span></td>
<td></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td height="16"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td height="30"></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#333333;">
<strong>Name:</strong></span></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; 
color:#333333;">'.$_POST['name'].'</span></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30"></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#333333;">
<strong>Email:</strong></span></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; 
color:#333333;">'.$_POST['email'].'</span></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30"></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#333333;">
<strong>Phone:</strong></span></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; 
color:#333333;">'.$_POST['phone'].'</span></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td height="30"></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#333333;">
<strong>Day in:</strong></span></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; 
color:#333333;">'.$_POST['dayin'].'</span></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30"></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#333333;">
<strong>Day out:</strong></span></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;
color:#333333;">'.$_POST['dayout'].'</span></td>
<td></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td height="30"></td>
<td valign="middle"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#333333;">
<strong>Comments:</strong></span></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="190"></td>
<td colspan="2" valign="top"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; 
color:#333333;">'.$_POST['comments'].'</span></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td height="20"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now when I add this form in my php and submit my form ... I receive my submission that doesn't look like the table layout like above.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following headers. These will allow you to just put normal HTML in your message.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <example@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: example two@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Hi Spacebeers,

Thanks for your help. Ok, I changed my headers to allow HTML, then I added a basic HTML layout for my email output but for some reason there is no color or the CSS is not working. Why is that?

Please see my EDIT in my question above of what I've done, thanks.

Comment: I might be wrong (not in a position to test it at the moment) but you'd be better off using inline styles for HTML emails. Specially for Outlook. Try adding inline styles to the td and see if that helps. It's a pain but that's Outlook for you.

Comment: Also for Outlook you're going to struggle with background-image.

Comment: In fact to save a headache for you later here's a good article on CSS in emails - http://css-tricks.com/133-using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

If you think cross browser testing is bad, wait till you've done cross email program testing...

Comment: Inline styling is fine for me and I don't want to use a background image, just maybe a background color. I read the CSSTRICKS LINK and it certainly has some good tips.

My Problem now is that when I put my designed HTML layout in my php form (SEE IT IN MY EDIT ABOVE IN MY QUESTION), it doesn't come out like that when I submit the form, almost like it isn't using the CSS from the inline styles.

Comment: Do you have a link online I can look at?

Comment: This is how the HTML email should look like - http://www.testing123.co.za/email-layout.jpg and this is how it turns out: http://www.testing123.co.za/incorrect.jpg .

Comment: what email broswer are you seeing this in?

Answer (score 1):

Yep you are going to have to use

```
Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n
```

It might be a good idea to provide your email in both HTML and text formats as not all email applications support HTML, and many others support it poorly.

To do so use this header instead. The boundary thing is what separates the HTML and text versions in the email, the line below generates a unique code which is suitable for this purpose

```
$boundary = md5(date('r', time())); 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=$boundary."\"";
```

Before the text version of the email post this code, note the "--" at the begging. You use the same boundary throughout the email.

```
--<?php echo $boundary; ?>
```

Before the HTML version post the same code again

There is a good template you can use here
http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php